# How is a 3D complex array laid out in memory

Tags: fortran, fftw

I would like to know how a 3d complex array is laid out in a computer's memory? An example in Fortran would be of some help.

I'm trying to do a 1-dimensional sine transformation of a 3d complex array and I'm using a routine from FFTW. http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs

So I need to figure out the values for the parameters(i.e.howmany, istride and idist) in the FFT routine. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention.

Comment: Have a look at [section 6.5 of the standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) and especially section 6.5.3.2

Comment: No indication of this is a fortran problem, but you can look for detail at http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Calling-FFTW-from-Modern-Fortran.htm, if you could give some piece of code that is not working as you expected, someone might be able to point out where goes wrong.

Comment: You are asking for an example. You have already received one answer. Do you find it insufficient? In which way? What kind of example would you want? A picture of the array? Or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex Fortran scalar values are stored as pairs of values [real, imaginary]. All Fortran arrays are [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), that means that the first index is the most frequently changing one. And each element of a complex array is a (real, imaginary) pair.

A Fortran array

```
complex(c_float_complex) :: A(nx, ny, nz)
```

is like a C array

```
float A[nz][ny][nx][2]
```

(yes, I know there is an optional complex type in modern C as well).

So the sequence goes like this:

```
(re(1,1,1),im(1,1,1)), (re(2,1,1,),im(2,1,1)), (re(3,1,1,),im(3,1,1)) ... (re(nx,1,1,),im(nx,1,1)), (re(1,2,1),im(1,2,1)) ...
```

Se the [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) link for more details.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir F. The sequence was what I was looking for.